# Notifications sound Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps

```
 ToastTemplateType toastType = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02;
           XmlDocument toastXML = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastType);
           XmlNodeList toastText = toastXML.GetElementsByTagName("text");
           XmlNodeList toastImages = toastXML.GetElementsByTagName("image");
           toastText[0].InnerText = "Funny cat";
           toastText[1].InnerText = "This cat looks like it's trying to eat your face.";
           ((XmlElement)toastImages[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/washer.png");
           ((XmlElement)toastImages[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "Scary Cat Face");

           //This is the options code, which is all optional based on your needs.
           IXmlNode toastNode = toastXML.SelectSingleNode("/toast");

           ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

           XmlElement audioNode = toastXML.CreateElement("audio");

           audioNode.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/beep.wav");

           //Must be used when looping audio has been selected.
           audioNode.SetAttribute("loop", "true");
           toastNode.AppendChild(audioNode);

           //You can append any text data you would like to the optional
           //launch property, but clicking a Toast message should drive
           //the user to something contextually relevant.
           ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "<cat state='angry'><facebite state='true' /></cat>");

           ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXML);
           ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

So I took this code from a webpage and it works but there is a detail. The sound it plays is not the one I want it to play... even if specify the name and assets it looks like it plays some sound from microsoft? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug in windows 10 and there is no solution to it at the moment. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10.aspx

> "...custom audio isn't working. We're investigating this issue. Both
>   ms-appx and ms-appdata don't work on Desktop, and only ms-appdata work
>   on Mobile."

Answer (score 0):

Toast notifications can only play a fixed set of system provided sounds - for example, `ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Mail`.  The default sound will be played if a specific sound is not specified, or if an invalid `src` is provided.

The full list of supported sounds can be found in [this documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761492.aspx).